# How to echo predefined variable from PowerShell command line?

Tags: powershell, variables, echo, predefined-variables, write-host

I'm able to `Write-Host` a custom variable from PowerShell command line, but predefined variables are not working with same way.

What is proper way to echo a predefined variable.

`Write-Host $path` works.
`Write-Host $PSScriptRoot` does not.

Here is my code.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& { $path = """test"""; Write-Host $path; Write-Host $PSScriptRoot; }"
```

I would like to have **parent** directory of current script as variable.

Something like this `$RootPath = Split-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent) -Parent`.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` is defined for scripts in files. You're not running a file-based script, so `$PSScriptRoot` is empty. If you want the current directory, use `pwd` or `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory`  (depending on whether you want PowerShell's opinion, or the operating system's opinion).

Comment: @JeroenMostert would you please provide an example for both?

Comment: `Write-Host (Split-Path (pwd) -Parent)`? Or set a variable first: `$path = pwd`. This is a basic case of using a cmdlet's output as input for another cmdlet.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was seaching this solution more than 3 hours. I really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If current location is what you want, this has always worked for me.

```
(Get-Location).path
```

If you also want to know for other predefined variables, Write host should work.

`Get-Variable` or simply `Variable` will display all predefined variables. If you look at `$PSScriptroot`, you will realize that it is empty. That is why it doesn't seem to be working for you.